# Search And replace text with iTextSharp can't detect the whole world C#

Tags: c#, itext

Hello there please I am facing a problem with searching and replacing a whole word with iTextSharp in a PDF.In fact the algorithme compare chunk with my WholeWorld and the chunk contain only three or two words. So the algorithme didn't find my exact word.

Here is my code:
Program.cs

```
using testProject;

string sourceFile = @"C:\oldFile.pdf";
string descFile = @"C:\test.pdf";
PDFEdit pdfObj = new PDFEdit();
pdfObj.ReplaceTextInPDF(sourceFile, descFile, "client", "hello");
```

PDFEdit.cs:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.Drawing;

namespace testProject
{
    public class PDFEdit
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Find the text and replace in PDF
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sourceFile">The source PDF file where text to be searched</param>
        /// <param name="descFile">The new destination PDF file which will be saved with replaced text</param>
        /// <param name="textToBeSearched">The text to be searched in the PDF</param>
        /// <param name="textToBeReplaced">The text to be replaced with</param>
        public void ReplaceTextInPDF(string sourceFile, string descFile, string textToBeSearched, string textToBeReplaced)
        {
            ReplaceText(textToBeSearched, textToBeReplaced, descFile, sourceFile);
        }
        private void ReplaceText(string textToBeSearched, string textToAdd, string outputFilePath, string inputFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                using (Stream outputPdfStream2 = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    //Opens the unmodified PDF for reading
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
                    //Creates a stamper to put an image on the original pdf
                    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream); //{ FormFlattening = true, FreeTextFlattening = true };
                    for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        var tt = new MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy(textToBeSearched);
                        var ex = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader).ProcessContent(i, tt, new Dictionary<string, IContentOperator>()).GetResultantText();
                       // var ex = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, tt); // ex will be holding the text, although we just need the rectangles [RectAndText class objects]
                        foreach (var p in tt.myPoints)
                        {
                            //Creates an image that is the size i need to hide the text i'm interested in removing
                            Bitmap transparentBitmap = new Bitmap((int)p.Rect.Width, (int)p.Rect.Height);
                            transparentBitmap.MakeTransparent();
                            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(new Bitmap(130, 20), BaseColor.BLACK);
                            //Sets the position that the image needs to be placed (ie the location of the text to be removed)
                            image.SetAbsolutePosition(p.Rect.Left, (p.Rect.Top - 8));
                            //Adds the image to the output pdf
                            stamper.GetOverContent(i).AddImage(image, true); // i stands for the page no.

                            PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(i);

                            // select the font properties
                            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                            cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 7);

                            // write the text in the pdf content
                            cb.BeginText();
                            // put the alignment and coordinates here
                            cb.ShowTextAligned(1, textToAdd, p.Rect.Left + 10, p.Rect.Top - 6, 0);
                            cb.EndText();
                        }
                    }
                    //Creates the first copy of the outputted pdf
                    stamper.Close();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy.cs :

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;


namespace testProject
{
    internal class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
    {
        //Hold each coordinate
        public List<RectAndText> myPoints = new List<RectAndText>();

        //The string that we're searching for
        public String TextToSearchFor { get; set; }

        //How to compare strings
        public System.Globalization.CompareOptions CompareOptions { get; set; }

        public MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy(String textToSearchFor, System.Globalization.CompareOptions compareOptions = System.Globalization.CompareOptions.None)
        {
            this.TextToSearchFor = textToSearchFor;
            this.CompareOptions = compareOptions;
        }

        //Automatically called for each chunk of text in the PDF
        public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {

            base.RenderText(renderInfo);
            //See if the current chunk contains the text
            //var startPosition = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(renderInfo.GetText(), this.TextToSearchFor, this.CompareOptions);
            Console.WriteLine(renderInfo.GetText());
            var startPosition = -1;
            if (this.TextToSearchFor.Contains(renderInfo.GetText()))
            {
                startPosition = 0;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(startPosition);

            //If not found bail
            if (startPosition < 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            //Grab the individual characters
            var chars = renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos().Skip(startPosition).Take(this.TextToSearchFor.Length).ToList();

            //Grab the first and last character
            var firstChar = chars.First();
            var lastChar = chars.Last();


            //Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
            var bottomLeft = firstChar.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
            var topRight = lastChar.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

            //Create a rectangle from it
            var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(bottomLeft[Vector.I1], bottomLeft[Vector.I2], topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]);

            //Add this to our main collection
            this.myPoints.Add(new RectAndText(rect, this.TextToSearchFor));
        }
    }
}
```

RectAndText.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testProject
{
    internal class RectAndText
    {
        public iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Rect;
        public String Text;
        public RectAndText(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, String text)
        {
            this.Rect = rect;
            this.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```